# Does a Stripe payment intent place a hold before or after confirmation?

Tags: stripe-payments

From what I understand, payment intents serve to place a hold on a card for a specific amount in more complex, asynchronous payment processes, allowing the merchant to charge the card—i.e., *capture* the held amount—at a later point. In Stripe's API, payment intents have a [`create`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create), [`confirm`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm), and [`capture`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture) method (I'm using the Ruby gem).

The creation, confirmation, and capture of a payment intent are three distinct steps that happen in that order over time.

I have read the docs for all three methods, but one thing that's unclear to me is the following:

**Does a payment intent place a hold on a card when the intent is *created*, or does the hold occur only after the payment intent is *confirmed*?**

My current conjecture is that the answer is "the hold is placed during the payment intent's creation," since I think the flow is the following:

1. *Creation* of the payment intent places a hold/authorizes the card
2. *Confirmation* of the payment intent charges the card (as per the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm): "Upon confirmation, the PaymentIntent will attempt to initiate a payment.")
3. *Capture* of the payment intent pays out the funds to the merchant

To my surprise, Stripe customer support has been unable to answer this question, and when exactly the hold occurs doesn't seem to be mentioned explicitly anywhere I could find.

Comment: Per [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm), confirmation causes an attempt to initiate a payment. That's when the card is actually authorized.

An authorization (hold) will happen upon confirmation in the optional [manual capture](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later) flow. Otherwise with automatic capture, the confirmation will cause capture immediately (there is no hold).

Comment: @taintedzodiac I read "Upon confirmation, the PaymentIntent will attempt to initiate a payment" as meaning *that's when money is moved*. That doesn't read to me as putting a hold on the card—which doesn't move any money yet. Or am I misreading that line?

Comment: Initiating a payment is the authorization part (the hold). Unless you use manual capture, the held money is immediately captured. Thus for most payments, it's irrelevant to worry about the hold as it's only in that specific case that it actually matters.

Comment: I do use manual capture, since I want the hold and the capture to be separate in time. I don't understand the point of a payment intent without that separation—expect maybe not having to make a wholly different API call and instead being able to change the single manual flag for developer convenience... In any case, OK, if the confirmation is required for the hold to occur, I'll need to change some things. Put that as the answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear explanation with examples [here](https://stripe.com/en-gb-us/resources/more/card-authorization-explained#what-is-a-card-authorisation-hold).

> When the card issuer reviews an authorisation request for a transaction, if there are enough funds available to cover the cost of the sale, the issuer will place an authorisation hold on the cardholder's account. This will reduce their available funds or credit by the amount of the sale in order to prevent them from potentially overdrawing the account before the funds from the current transaction are moved and sent to the business's bank. Authorisation holds are a helpful mechanism for preventing card fraud and chargebacks.

Comment: "When the card issuer reviews an authorisation request for a transaction" It's unclear from that quote whether that review happens upon creation, confirmation, or capture, so it doesn't answer my question. [Per taintedzodiac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347030/does-a-stripe-payment-intent-place-a-hold-before-or-after-confirmation/77723053#comment115528237_65347030), it's the confirmation that places a hold on the card.